# Remove Zurb Foundation Inline Styling

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

I'm actually working on my website and trying to implement a modal.
Since I'm using Foundation, I wish I'd be able to use the included 'reveal' plugin so I don't have to build the thing...since I don't know much about JS.

The implementation was easy until I looked at the mobile view and noticed the modal is going full screen. Wish I'd like to avoid. After battling with the CSS I realise Foundation is adding an inline style:

```
<div class="reveal" id="noChroma" style="top: 0px;">
```

Notice the "top:0px" that is added probably from the "foundation.js". I don't want to mess with this file.

Is there a way I can bypass this style and force mine, like "top:70vh"?
I tried "!important" but the javascript always wins.

[You can see it here](http://www.quentinbeau.com)

Thank you for your help,
Best,

Quentin

Comment: your `top:70vh !important` works. But only for this media query:


```
@media screen and (max-width: 639px)
.reveal {
    display: block;
    top: 70vh !important;
}
```

You also have to set it for the other sizes.

Comment: If you trigger the modal on a browser and resize, it seems to be working. But if you trigger the modal while already at mobile size, then the JS overwrites the !important.

Answer (score 0):

> If you trigger the modal on a browser and resize, it seems to be working. But if you trigger the modal while already at mobile size, then the JS overwrites the !important. – Quentin Beau Kwint

I can't reproduce this behavior. (screenshot)

The `!important` css wins here. Even if i reload the site and trigger again.

[image]

Comment: Ah ok, now i see :)

Comment: You can try to override it with javascript. Just for quick testing you can add a onclick attribute to the trigger button.

`<a href="#" data-toggle="noChroma" aria-controls="noChroma" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" onclick="Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('reveal-overlay')).forEach(e => e.style.top = '70vh')">`

Comment: ok thx! Tried it. In your example you are adding the style to "reveal-overlay" which is the dark background. So everything is pushed down including the background.
When I set it to 'reveal' only, its not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

See https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/reveal.html

This is done by https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop/js/foundation.reveal.js#L132 which is controlled by `data-v-offset`

Related issues and some workarounds: https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/pull/9763#issuecomment-332219355

https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/10662

Comment: Thx, I tried the data-v-offset previously but unless i'm mistaken it doesn't work. It forces using Pixels, which is way too restrictive and lack flexibility. Although, it applies to everything, regardless screen size. Can' find a solution in the other links.